# Search between brackets [_] find underscore and output echo result "OK" or "FAIL"

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I have `cat /proc/mdstat` output follows. I just want to export echo "OK" or "FAIL" if there is `_` underscore between ANY of `[]` brackets. How would I do that?

```
[root@srv4 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md6 : active raid10 sda6[0] sdd6[3] sdb6[1] sdc6[2]
      7237440512 blocks 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/54 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md5 : active raid10 sdb5[1] sda5[0] sdc5[2] sdd5[3]
      153594880 blocks 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]

md3 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdc3[2] sdb3[1] sdd3[3]
      209918912 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      523200 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]
```

```
[root@srv2 public]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md6 : active raid1 sda6[0] sdb6[1]
      1588416448 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/12 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md5 : active raid1 sdb5[1] sda5[0]
      153597888 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/2 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      209918912 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 1/2 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      523200 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

More likely it is going to be either `[_UU]` or `[_UUUU]`

Expected result:

```
if there is no [_] between any of brackets is "OK" 
if there is [_] between any of brackets is "FAIL"
```

Comment: Since neither of your files contain a match, it should be better to include just one file for brevity's sake. What do you mean with *export* echo OK/FAIL?

Comment: I assume you do not expect to find a `_`  in the size or count brackets e.g.  [5KB] or [2/2].  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -q '\[.*_.*]' /proc/mdstat
then
        echo FAIL
else
        echo OK
fi
```

This simply checks whether any line in the input contains a `[`,
followed by an `_`, followed by a `]`, in that order,
but (possibly) with other characters intermixed. 
Being a simple solution, it is imperfect; it considers

```
sda6[0] _sdb6[1]
```

to match the pattern.

This version:

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -q '\[[^]]*_.*]' /proc/mdstat
then
        echo FAIL
else
        echo OK
fi
```

requires that the `[` be followed by an `_`
***with no intervening `]` characters***
(retaining the requirement that the `_` be eventually followed by a `]`. 
This will still count

```
sda6[0_ sdb6[1]
```

as having an `_` between brackets. 
As far as I’m concerned, the interpretation of this input is ambiguous,
and I don’t really care,
since the question doesn’t say how to handle malformed data.

Comment: this solution works for me because _ can be anywhere between [UU_UU] or [_U] when a raid failed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU grep in PCRE mode...

Assuming you are actually only interested in the final entry on the status line for a device, i.e. `[some_combination_of U and _]` which represents the up/down status of each raid device, either `U` for up or `_` for down - which your question implies but does not explicitly state.

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -Pq '\[[[:alpha:]]*?(_){1,}[[:alpha:]]*?\]' /proc/mdstat
then
    echo "FAIL"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

If you actually want all instances of '_' within square brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -Pq '\[[^]](_){1,}.*?\]' /proc/mdstat
then
    echo "FAIL"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```

You can write `(_){1,}` as `_{1,}` if you so wish; the result is the same.  My style for such regex is to use parenthesis.

Comment: (1) I see that you have assumed that `[_5KB]` doesn’t count as an underscore between brackets, although the OP hasn’t said so. (2) As far as I can tell, your answer works the same if you take out the `?`s and the parentheses around the `_`.  Can you justify why you need them?

Comment: hi updated solution is also works. thank you.